# Printing numbers from 1-100 then storing it in a txt file

Tags: javascript

So I made a simple code to print numbers from 1 to 100 and it works just fine,
but I want to store every number in a text file, so every number from 1 to 100 would be stored in its own line, Issue I have is that its only storing the last number

```
const fs = require('fs')

for(var i = 1; i < 100; i++){
let data = `(1, ${i}, 0, 'Game Channel ${i}', '1'),`

fs.writeFile('Output.txt', data, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
})}
```

For example in txt file output would be:

```
(1, 1, 0, 'Game Channel 1', '1'),
(1, 2, 0, 'Game Channel 2', '1')
```

Comment: `fs.writeFileSync` maybe?  What problem are you having?

Comment: Its only storing the last number

Comment: It is constantly overriding each value. Append to the file instead of rewriting it. Also use `fs.writeFileSync` since the function is not async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write at the end, since you're be overwriting it on every subsequent write.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

let data = "";

for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    data += `(1, ${i}, 0, 'Game Channel ${i}', '1'),\n`;
}

fs.writeFile('Output.txt', data, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

Comment: pls do not append 100 times to a string! Pls, push every line in an array and join it with line end.

Comment: @Scriptkiddy1337 if anything, your approach would have even more string operations and be less efficient

Comment: Oooh thank you, also now it stores everything in a single line, can I make it store data in a new line each time?

Comment: just add a `\n` to the end of each string

Answer (score 0):

You can use `createWriteStream` to open the file, and then write to it asynchronously.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

async function main() {
  const ws = fs.createWriteStream('output.txt');
  for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    let data = `(1, ${i}, 0, 'Game Channel ${i}', '1'),\n`
    await ws.write(data);
  }
}
main();
```

Answer (score 0):

First build whole combined string and then write to file.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const data = Array.from({length: 100}, (_, i) => `(1, ${i+1}, 0, 'Game Channel ${i+1}', '1'),\n`).join('')

fs.writeFile('Output.txt', data, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```